# How do I change a button in SwiftUI after a button is pressed

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode12, macos-big-sur

I want a card image to change to another card image when I press a button. This is my current code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

var leftCard = "green_back"
var rightCard = "blue_back"

func dealCards() {
    leftCard = "1C"
    print("deal")
}

struct GameView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                Image(leftCard)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                Image(rightCard)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
            .padding(.all, 25)
            
            Button(action: dealCards) {
                Text("Deal Cards")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(10)
                    .border(Color.blue, width: 5)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GameView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GameView()
    }
}
```

This code prints "deal" when I press the button, but it doesn't change the image.

I am using MacOS Big Sur beta 3 and Xcode 12 beta 2.

Edit: I just had to move my variables into the GameView struct and add a `@State` modifier to them. Thanks to everyone who answered. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should update your `Images` and should give you a random value as well in the `deal()` function.

It is very important that you define your properties and functions inside a `View` or component. Global variables are generally not recommended and can lead to unexpected results.

```
import SwiftUI

struct GameView: View {

    // 1. Add ImageName to handle names via dot (.) to avoid mistyping strings. CaseIterable allow you to get an array of all the values defined.
    enum ImageName: String, CaseIterable {
        case greenBack = "green_back"
        case blueBack = "blue_back"
        case other = "1C"
    }

    // 2. Add @State to update the GameView() automatically when any of the properties are updated.
    @State private var leftCard: ImageName = .greenBack
    @State private var rightCard: ImageName = .blueBack

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {

                // 3. Add .rawValue to get the raw String value
                Image(leftCard.rawValue)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

                Image(rightCard.rawValue)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
            .padding(.all, 25)

            Button(action: dealCards) {
                Text("Deal Cards")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(10)
                    .border(Color.blue, width: 5)
            }
        }
    }

    func dealCards() {
        // 4. Update the name via dot(.) of any card that you want.
        // You can also randomise the card doing .allCases.randomElement()
        leftCard = ImageName.allCases.randomElement() ?? .greenBack
        print("deal")
    }
}

struct GameView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GameView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even remove the function and add the code directly to button

```swift
struct GameView: View {
    
    @State var leftCard = "green_back"
    @State var rightCard = "blue_back"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                Image(leftCard)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                
                Image(rightCard)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
            .padding(.all, 25)
            
            Button(action: {
                self.leftCard = "1C"
            }) {
                
                Text("Deal Cards")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(10)
                    .border(Color.blue, width: 5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this, but this doesn't make a code any more *readable* or *clearer*.

Comment: If there are only few lines of code for button action , i prefer to write them directly in button - that makes. clear without going to the function what the button will do. It does not make code more unreadable at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your variables to the `GameView` and add `@State` modifier:

```
struct GameView: View {
    @State var leftCard = "green_back"
    @State var rightCard = "blue_back"
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
    
    func dealCards() {
        leftCard = "1C"
        print("deal")
    }
}
```

This way SwiftUI will refresh the view when your `@State` variables change.